# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a} =1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

This was a practice problem I was given.

> Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a} =1$.

My argument is as follows:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a}
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\ln(\sqrt[n]{a})} \\
&= e^{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{n}) \ln(a)} \\
&= e^{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(0 \cdot \ln(a))} \\
&= e^0 \\
&= 1.\end{align}

Comment: There was a discussion about this yesterday here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678309/derivative-of-ax-from-first-principles/678361#comment1424801_678361

Comment: your solution does not have errors.

Comment: You must assume that $a>0$.

Comment: You should simply consider rewriting $\sqrt[n]{a}$ as $a^{\frac{1}{n}}$. As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this one is due to Courant:

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $a_{n}$ such that 
$$
a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n}-1
$$
Note that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_{n}\geqslant0$. Now rewrite
as:
\begin{eqnarray*}
n & = & \left(a_{n}+1\right)^{n}\\
 & = & \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_{n}^{k}\\
 & \geqslant & \binom{n}{2}a_{n}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
We get $n\geqslant\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a_{n}^{2}$.

After rearranging:

$$
a_{n}\leqslant\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0
$$
Concluding that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1
$$

Comment: This seems extremely complicated - what are the advantages versus the sort of solution I proposed in my answer?

Comment: Advantages? I don't know. I think it's a nice proof.

Comment: Its bit surprising that you have solved a different question concerning $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}$ whereas OP asked for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}$ for $a > 0$. Even more difficult is to be believe that OP accepted your answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: it seems customary that POs accept answers without checking them...

Answer (score 4):

Take any number $r>1$. Eventually $r^n>a$ and so eventually $\sqrt[n]a<r$. Now take $r<1$. Eventually $r^n<a$ and so eventually $\sqrt[n]a>r$.

Calculating $\lim\ r^n$ rigorously is a little tricky and depends on how deep you want to go, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/308277/30481) for one approach.

I did also use the fact that the $n$-th root function is increasing, but I'm not sure how to prove that without diving into the definition of the ordering in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your approach is very simple so +1 for that. Regarding the increasing nature of $n$-th root its not difficult at all. If $a > b > 0$ and $n$ is positive integer then it is very easy to show that $a^{n} > b^{n}$ (just multiply $a > b\,\,$ $n$ times). Next let $c > d > 0$. Clearly if $c^{1/n} \leq d^{1/n}$ then from the previous result we must have $c \leq d$ which is not the case. Hence $c^{1/n} > d^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an essential piece in your reasoning, as you swap a limit and a function (the logarithm): you must state that *the function is continuous*.

You may have simply written
$$\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]a\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\sqrt[n]a\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log a}n\right)=0.$$